# script only works on the first time (id is repeating)

Tags: javascript, php

I have this uploading script and the form in the loop..it all works but the the  `document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";` only works on the first iteration can any one help ?

```
<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
    // Create the iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

    // Add to document...
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

    iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function () {

            if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
            else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

            // Message from server...
            if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.document) {
                content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
            }

            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

            // Del the iframe...
            setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
        }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    // Set properties of form...
    form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the form...
    form.submit();

    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
}
</script>

<!-- index.php could be any script server-side for receive uploads. -->
<form>
<input type="file" name="myFile" /></br>
  <input type="hidden" name="fid"  readonly value="<?php  echo $fid;?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="numerolinha"  readonly value="<?php  echo $loader;?>"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="contador"  readonly value="<?php  echo $id_postt1."linha_".$events[0];  ?>">
<input type="button" value="upload" class="button white small"
        onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/wallet_upload.php','upload'); return false;" >
<div id="upload"></div>
</form></div>
```

Comment: its a while that repeats this form

Comment: So the while loop repeatedly shows the form?

Comment: Yes ! Many upload forms and everything works fine but the uploading message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With every loop you are creating a div with id of 'upload'.

The fileUpload is then called, and it finds one of those (the first in the list of divs) with the id of 'upload' and sets the inner html to 'Uploading...' however the div still exists, and still exists with 'upload', so with the next upload it's going to set the inner html of the same (first) div.

You'll need to give each div a unique identifier.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $totalForms; $i++ ){
    ?>
    ...
    <input type="button" value="upload" class="button white small"
    onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/wallet_upload.php','upload<?php echo $i ?>'); return false;" >
<div id="upload<?php echo $i ?>"></div>
    ...
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but nothing happend...i have divs upload0..1..2 etc but im guessing the script still asking for div upload

Comment: When you view source can you confirm that the call to `fileUpload` has the correct id as the last parameter?

Comment: i had forgot that !! tks alot richard ! :)) it work :) oh some one voted my question down and now im banned ! :( ill try to vou u up anyways  :) tks

Answer (score 1):

If you let php oputput this form several times you are repeating

```
<div id="upload"></div>
```

but the id must be unique in the DOM otherwise

```
document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
```

will not work correctly. 
A broken DOM often produces for confusing JS errors and sends browsers into squirk mode making it hard to predict the experience of the respective visitor.

When you iterate through the loop create a unique ID for the tag everytime you loop through it

```
while( $i < 10){
/*###### everything esle in the loop */
 $i++; $divID = 'myID'.$i; 
echo '<div id="'.$divID.'"></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Yes i get that but still dont know how to fix my.code

Comment: when you iterate through the loop create a unique ID for the tag everytime you loop through it

while( $i < 10){
$i++;
$divID = 'myID'.$i;
echo '<div id="'.$divID.'"></div>'
}

Comment: My while is getting data from the database

Comment: well then set $i=0; before the loop starts and then do $i=++; inside the loop so $i will be higher with every iteration and so the resulting id of your div will be different everytime it is put out.

Comment: didnt work..maybe becouse theres no #divID ...its created on the script level